# How to run BeEF behind an nginx reverse proxy with SSL correctly

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm currently running BeEF on a Debian 10 VPS - version: '0.5.0.0-alpha-pre' installed using the standard install script on the GitHub archive.It is running behind a nginx reverse proxy on a VirtualHost with SSL configured (by certbot). BeEF is listening on an internal interface (not directly routeable from the internet), and nginx is proxying requests to the IP of that interface. Everything is working fine - the admin browser UI and even the hooks when using http. However when I try and embed the hook on an https page, the hook doesn't work. From the browser console (latest firefox on Linux), I get the message 'Blocked Mixed Active Content' repeatedly as the browser tries to connect to the hook/handler via an http URL. The SSL option in BeEF's config.yaml file exists, but that seems to be for when BeEF is not running behind a reverse proxy. Could someone please shed some light as to how to configure BeEF correctly to run behind an nginx reverse proxy.

My config.yaml file is below and below that I will paste my nginx config file as well for the particular server block in concern.

## BeEF Configuration file

```
beef:
    version: '0.5.0.0-alpha-pre'
    # More verbose messages (server-side)
    debug: false
    # More verbose messages (client-side)
    client_debug: false
    # Used for generating secure tokens
    crypto_default_value_length: 80

# Credentials to authenticate in BeEF.
# Used by both the RESTful API and the Admin interface
credentials:
    user:   "beef"
    passwd: "*********************"

# Interface / IP restrictions
restrictions:
    # subnet of IP addresses that can hook to the framework
    permitted_hooking_subnet: ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
    # subnet of IP addresses that can connect to the admin UI
    #permitted_ui_subnet: ["127.0.0.1/32", "::1/128"]
    permitted_ui_subnet: ["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
    # slow API calls to 1 every  api_attempt_delay  seconds
    api_attempt_delay: "0.05"

# HTTP server
http:
    debug: false #Thin::Logging.debug, very verbose. Prints also full exception stack trace.
    host: "172.17.0.1"
    port: "3000"

    # Decrease this setting to 1,000 (ms) if you want more responsiveness
    #  when sending modules and retrieving results.
    # NOTE: A poll timeout of less than 5,000 (ms) might impact performance
    #  when hooking lots of browsers (50+).
    # Enabling WebSockets is generally better (beef.websocket.enable)
    xhr_poll_timeout: 1000

    # Host Name / Domain Name
    # If you want BeEF to be accessible via hostname or domain name (ie, DynDNS),
    #   set the public hostname below:
    #public: "my.domain.org"      # public hostname/IP address

    # Reverse Proxy / NAT
    # If you want BeEF to be accessible behind a reverse proxy or NAT,
    #   set both the publicly accessible hostname/IP address and port below:
    # NOTE: Allowing the reverse proxy will enable a vulnerability where the ui/panel can be spoofed
    #   by altering the X-FORWARDED-FOR ip address in the request header.
    allow_reverse_proxy: true
    public: "my.domain.org"      # public hostname/IP address
    public_port: "443" # public port (experimental)

    # Hook
    hook_file: "/hook.js"
    hook_session_name: "BEEFHOOK"

    # Allow one or multiple origins to access the RESTful API using CORS
    # For multiple origins use: "http://browserhacker.com, http://domain2.com"
    restful_api:
        allow_cors: false
        cors_allowed_domains: "https://my.domain.org"

    # Prefer WebSockets over XHR-polling when possible.
    websocket:
        enable: false
        port: 61985 # WS: good success rate through proxies
        # Use encrypted 'WebSocketSecure'
        # NOTE: works only on HTTPS domains and with HTTPS support enabled in BeEF
        secure: true
        secure_port: 61986 # WSSecure
        ws_poll_timeout: 1000 # poll BeEF every second
        ws_connect_timeout: 500 # useful to help fingerprinting finish before establishing the WS channel

    # Imitate a specified web server (default root page, 404 default error page, 'Server' HTTP response header)
    web_server_imitation:
        enable: true
        type: "apache" # Supported: apache, iis, nginx
        hook_404: false # inject BeEF hook in HTTP 404 responses
        hook_root: false # inject BeEF hook in the server home page
    # Experimental HTTPS support for the hook / admin / all other Thin managed web services
    https:
        enable: false
        # In production environments, be sure to use a valid certificate signed for the value
        # used in beef.http.public (the domain name of the server where you run BeEF)
        key: "beef_key.pem"
        cert: "beef_cert.pem"

database:
    file: "beef.db"

# Autorun Rule Engine
autorun:
    # this is used when rule chain_mode type is nested-forward, needed as command results are checked via setInterval
    # to ensure that we can wait for async command results. The timeout is needed to prevent infinite loops or eventually
    # continue execution regardless of results.
    # If you're chaining multiple async modules, and you expect them to complete in more than 5 seconds, increase the timeout.
    result_poll_interval: 300
    result_poll_timeout: 5000

    # If the modules doesn't return status/results and timeout exceeded, continue anyway with the chain.
    # This is useful to call modules (nested-forward chain mode) that are not returning their status/results.
    continue_after_timeout: true

# Enables DNS lookups on zombie IP addresses
dns_hostname_lookup: false

# IP Geolocation
# NOTE: requires MaxMind database. Run ./updated-geoipdb to install.
geoip:
    enable: true
    database: '/opt/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'

# Integration with PhishingFrenzy
# If enabled BeEF will try to get the UID parameter value from the hooked URI, as this is used by PhishingFrenzy
# to uniquely identify the victims. In this way you can easily associate phishing emails with hooked browser.
integration:
    phishing_frenzy:
        enable: false

# You may override default extension configuration parameters here
# Note: additional experimental extensions are available in the 'extensions' directory
#       and can be enabled via their respective 'config.yaml' file
extension:
    admin_ui:
        enable: true
        base_path: "/ui"
    demos:
        enable: true
    events:
        enable: true
    evasion:
        enable: false
    requester:
        enable: true
    proxy:
        enable: true
    network:
        enable: true
    metasploit:
        enable: false
    social_engineering:
        enable: true
    xssrays:
        enable: true
```

And here's my NGINX config for that virtualhost

```
server {
            server_name my.domain.org;
            set $upstream 172.17.0.1:3000;
        location / {
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        proxy_pass http://$upstream;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection “”;
        proxy_buffering off;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }
```

I'm confident that the SSL is setup right because I've debugged and tested everything out in multiple ways. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I am not familiar with BEEF, but how does BEEF backend know if SSL is in use or not? You should have two unencrypted HTTP ports for your backend, one you use for normal traffic and the other for the terminated SSL traffic. This way your backend will perform non-ssl to SSL redirections correctly.

Comment: @Geoffrey that makes sense. I don't think the BeEF framework in it's current form supports what you're talking about. It can use SSL but only directly, not behind a reverse proxy where SSL is being terminated. I could write some Ruby and solve the issue, but I'm sure there's a more graceful way, especially since the authors of BeEF have mentioned that it should be run behind a reverse proxy in production mode. A cheap fix to this would be to simply change the handler URL to https from the code. I'm sure that would solve the 'Blocked Mixed Active Content' error.

Comment: The [tag:beef] tag is not for the browser exploitation framework.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the exact same issue, your proxy config actually helped me with one of my own issues.

In order to get this to work, you need to modify `./core/main/client/net.js` and hardcode the protocol sent to the javascript handlers to `https`. This will allow the whole system to function without SSL, but still generate SSL links for your reverse proxy to process.

Obviously a hack, but it will get it to work in a rush.

./core/main/client/net.js:

```
port: "<%= @beef_port %>",
hook: "<%= @beef_hook %>",
httpproto: "https",//"<%= @beef_proto %>", //<- Hardcoded to HTTPS
handler: '/dh',
chop: 500,
```

Comment: Please consider typing the code as it will make it easier to copy - past - search ...